# Webpack: Failed to decode downloaded font

Tags: css, webpack, vue.js

Using FontFaceObserver and getting a webpack error.

> Failed to decode downloaded font
>
> OTS parsing error: invalid version tag

**Webpack config**:

```
var path = require('path')
var utils = require('./utils')
var config = require('../config')
var vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
      : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src'),
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueLoaderConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.mp4$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('videos/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

At the top of **App.vue** stylesheet

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Pragmatica;
  font-weight: bold;
  src: url('/static/fonts/PragmaticaCond-Extrabold.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Pragmatica;
  src: url('/static/fonts/Pragmatica-Book.woff') format('woff');
}
```

My fonts sit within **static/fonts/**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It was a combination of a couple things. first was the path to the font file, I was setting the path as if there was no “build” happening, Webpack was putting them under /assetsafter release build so I had to update my path from /static/fonts to /fonts as after the build static files are automagically looked under assets folder + adding regex to support versioning in my webpack loader config + adding mimetype for woff files

Comment: at first was your fonts even downloading at all?  Just wondered

Comment: do you have an example?